# Scikit-learn decision tree extract nodes for feature

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a decision tree which has been trained on a dataset consisting of seven features. I would like some way of easily extracting each node where the data is split on a specific feature and which threshold or category is used as a split criteria.

This is the small template I am using to generate the tree.

```
clfSCReduced = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clfSCReduced.fit(featuresSC, labelsSC)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract rule path of data point through decision tree with sklearn python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553605/extract-rule-path-of-data-point-through-decision-tree-with-sklearn-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have marked the question as duplicate since I have addressed this here:

[Extract rule path of data point through decision tree with sklearn python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553605/extract-rule-path-of-data-point-through-decision-tree-with-sklearn-python/50556945#50556945)

I am also providing here, the main idea.
The following code is from the sklearn documentation with some small changes to address your goal.

---

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3, random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

# The decision estimator has an attribute called tree_  which stores the entire
# tree structure and allows access to low level attributes. The binary tree
# tree_ is represented as a number of parallel arrays. The i-th element of each
# array holds information about the node `i`. Node 0 is the tree's root. NOTE:
# Some of the arrays only apply to either leaves or split nodes, resp. In this
# case the values of nodes of the other type are arbitrary!
#
# Among those arrays, we have:
#   - left_child, id of the left child of the node
#   - right_child, id of the right child of the node
#   - feature, feature used for splitting the node
#   - threshold, threshold value at the node

n_nodes = estimator.tree_.node_count
children_left = estimator.tree_.children_left
children_right = estimator.tree_.children_right
feature = estimator.tree_.feature
threshold = estimator.tree_.threshold

# The tree structure can be traversed to compute various properties such
# as the depth of each node and whether or not it is a leaf.
node_depth = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=np.int64)
is_leaves = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=bool)
stack = [(0, -1)]  # seed is the root node id and its parent depth
while len(stack) > 0:
    node_id, parent_depth = stack.pop()
    node_depth[node_id] = parent_depth + 1

    # If we have a test node
    if (children_left[node_id] != children_right[node_id]):
        stack.append((children_left[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
        stack.append((children_right[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
    else:
        is_leaves[node_id] = True

print("The binary tree structure has %s nodes and has "
      "the following tree structure:"
      % n_nodes)
for i in range(n_nodes):
    if is_leaves[i]:
        print("%snode=%s leaf node." % (node_depth[i] * "\t", i))
    else:
        print("%snode=%s test node: go to node %s if X[:, %s] <= %s else to "
              "node %s."
              % (node_depth[i] * "\t",
                 i,
                 children_left[i],
                 feature[i],
                 threshold[i],
                 children_right[i],
                 ))
print("\n")

# First let's retrieve the decision path of each sample. The decision_path
# method allows to retrieve the node indicator functions. A non zero element of
# indicator matrix at the position (i, j) indicates that the sample i goes
# through the node j.

node_indicator = estimator.decision_path(X_test)

# Similarly, we can also have the leaves ids reached by each sample.

leave_id = estimator.apply(X_test)

# Now, it's possible to get the tests that were used to predict a sample or
# a group of samples. First, let's make it for the sample.

# HERE IS WHAT YOU WANT
sample_id = 0
node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                    node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]

print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
for node_id in node_index:

    if leave_id[sample_id] == node_id:  # <-- changed != to ==
        #continue # <-- comment out
        print("leaf node {} reached, no decision here".format(leave_id[sample_id])) # <--

    else: # < -- added else to iterate through decision nodes
        if (X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
            threshold_sign = "<="
        else:
            threshold_sign = ">"

        print("decision id node %s : (X[%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)"
              % (node_id,
                 sample_id,
                 feature[node_id],
                 X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]], # <-- changed i to sample_id
                 threshold_sign,
                 threshold[node_id]))
```

---

### This will print at the end the following:

```
Rules used to predict sample 0: 
decision id node 0 : (X[0, 3] (= 2.4) > 0.800000011920929)
decision id node 2 : (X[0, 2] (= 5.1) > 4.950000047683716)
leaf node 4 reached, no decision here
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `DecisionTreeClassifier` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html), it states that you can get the `Tree` object from `clsfSCReduced.tree_`.
The scikit-learn documentation has an example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py) on how to get out the information from trees.
The example gives the following output:

```
The binary tree structure has 5 nodes and has the following tree structure:
node=0 test node: go to node 1 if X[:, 3] <= 0.800000011920929 else to node 2.
        node=1 leaf node.
        node=2 test node: go to node 3 if X[:, 2] <= 4.950000047683716 else to node 4.
                node=3 leaf node.
                node=4 leaf node.

Rules used to predict sample 0:
decision id node 0 : (X_test[0, 3] (= 2.4) > 0.800000011920929)
decision id node 2 : (X_test[0, 2] (= 5.1) > 4.950000047683716)

The following samples [0, 1] share the node [0 2] in the tree
It is 40.0 % of all nodes.
```

I've copied their example below for completion

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3, random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

# The decision estimator has an attribute called tree_  which stores the entire
# tree structure and allows access to low level attributes. The binary tree
# tree_ is represented as a number of parallel arrays. The i-th element of each
# array holds information about the node `i`. Node 0 is the tree's root. NOTE:
# Some of the arrays only apply to either leaves or split nodes, resp. In this
# case the values of nodes of the other type are arbitrary!
#
# Among those arrays, we have:
#   - left_child, id of the left child of the node
#   - right_child, id of the right child of the node
#   - feature, feature used for splitting the node
#   - threshold, threshold value at the node
#

# Using those arrays, we can parse the tree structure:

n_nodes = estimator.tree_.node_count
children_left = estimator.tree_.children_left
children_right = estimator.tree_.children_right
feature = estimator.tree_.feature
threshold = estimator.tree_.threshold


# The tree structure can be traversed to compute various properties such
# as the depth of each node and whether or not it is a leaf.
node_depth = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=np.int64)
is_leaves = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=bool)
stack = [(0, -1)]  # seed is the root node id and its parent depth
while len(stack) > 0:
    node_id, parent_depth = stack.pop()
    node_depth[node_id] = parent_depth + 1

    # If we have a test node
    if (children_left[node_id] != children_right[node_id]):
        stack.append((children_left[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
        stack.append((children_right[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
    else:
        is_leaves[node_id] = True

print("The binary tree structure has %s nodes and has "
      "the following tree structure:"
      % n_nodes)
for i in range(n_nodes):
    if is_leaves[i]:
        print("%snode=%s leaf node." % (node_depth[i] * "\t", i))
    else:
        print("%snode=%s test node: go to node %s if X[:, %s] <= %s else to "
              "node %s."
              % (node_depth[i] * "\t",
                 i,
                 children_left[i],
                 feature[i],
                 threshold[i],
                 children_right[i],
                 ))
print()

# First let's retrieve the decision path of each sample. The decision_path
# method allows to retrieve the node indicator functions. A non zero element of
# indicator matrix at the position (i, j) indicates that the sample i goes
# through the node j.

node_indicator = estimator.decision_path(X_test)

# Similarly, we can also have the leaves ids reached by each sample.

leave_id = estimator.apply(X_test)

# Now, it's possible to get the tests that were used to predict a sample or
# a group of samples. First, let's make it for the sample.

sample_id = 0
node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                    node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]

print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
for node_id in node_index:
    if leave_id[sample_id] == node_id:
        continue

    if (X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
        threshold_sign = "<="
    else:
        threshold_sign = ">"

    print("decision id node %s : (X_test[%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)"
          % (node_id,
             sample_id,
             feature[node_id],
             X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]],
             threshold_sign,
             threshold[node_id]))

# For a group of samples, we have the following common node.
sample_ids = [0, 1]
common_nodes = (node_indicator.toarray()[sample_ids].sum(axis=0) ==
                len(sample_ids))

common_node_id = np.arange(n_nodes)[common_nodes]

print("\nThe following samples %s share the node %s in the tree"
      % (sample_ids, common_node_id))
print("It is %s %% of all nodes." % (100 * len(common_node_id) / n_nodes,))
```